# Finding lines that are not parallel to one another

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given the problem:

Let **u = (3,3,2)** and **v = (-1,0,1)**.  Which one of the following lines is not parallel to the other three?

a) **x** = 2**u** + t**v**

b) **x** = **u** +  2t**v**

c) **x** =  t**u** + **v**

d) **x** = 3t**v**

I must be doing it wrong as I get **(5, 6, 5)** for **(a)** from **2(3, 3, 2) + t(-1, 0, 1)**, and **(1, 3, 4)** for **(b)** from **(3, 3, 2) + 2t(-1, 0, 1)** for example when I try to substitute **u** and **v** into the line equations of **(a)** and **(b)**. I tried solving for **c**  here, (5**c**, 6**c**, 5**c**) = (1, 3, 4) to test if **(a)** and **(b)** are parallel, but they aren't, which isn't right as the answer is supposed to be option **(c)**, where **x** =  t**u** + **v**. What is the correct method of finding a line is not parallel to others?

Comment: You found one point on each of two lines. There is no way to tell whether lines are parallel by looking at just one point on each line. For a moment, forget about this particular problem and think how you can know whether lines are parallel when you are given them in vector form.

Comment: Define a line that you know intersects one of the lines. Then determine which of the others intersect that line at the same angles as the first, and so on until one intersects at different angles, and that is your line that is non parallel to the others https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Parallel_transversal.svg

Comment: @Adam These lines are in three-dimensional space.

Comment: I guess so, but the principle still applies albeit a bit more leg work no? Surely I mean they aren't even three dimensional objects

Comment: if line a) is perpendicular to our reference transversal, is b) and d) also going to be perpendicular to that line if they are parallel to a)?

Comment: Otherwise I guess I would go with the option of demonstrating three of them lie on a common plane, and one of them does not lie on that plane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines a), b), and d) have the direction given by vector $\mathbf v$, and therefore are parallel to each other. But line c) has the direction given by vector $\mathbf u$, which is *not* parallel to $\mathbf v$. So, yes, the answer is c).